# Remove row if it is same as previous row, with exception of one column

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, row

I have the following dataframe

```
x <- data.frame(id = c(1:6), 
                a = c('a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c'), 
                b = rep(2, 6), 
                c = c(5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2))

> x
  id a b c
1  1 a 2 5
2  2 b 2 4
3  3 b 2 4
4  4 a 2 5
5  5 a 2 5
6  6 c 2 2
```

I want to end up with

```
  id a b c
1  1 a 2 5
2  2 b 2 4
4  4 a 2 5
6  6 c 2 2
```

Requirement is that I want to remove the row if it is the same as the previous row, with the exception of the column `id`. If it is the same as a column further up the column but not immediately previous I do not want to get rid of it. For example id4 is the same as id1 but not removed, as it is not immediately above it.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use  `base R`

```
x[!c(FALSE, !rowSums(x[-1, -1] != x[-nrow(x), -1])),]
#  id a b c
#1  1 a 2 5
#2  2 b 2 4
#4  4 a 2 5
#6  6 c 2 2
```

Comment: This would work, but I have it in a generic function and I cannot guarantee the id column will be the first column so would be dangerous to use this methid

Comment: @user1165199  If you need to use the names `nm1 <- setdiff(names(x), "id");  x[!c(FALSE, !rowSums(x[-1, nm1] != x[-nrow(x), nm1])),]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `lag` function in `dplyr`. The idea is creating a key column and check whether it's the same as previous one.

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  mutate(key=paste(a, b, c, sep="|")) %>%
  filter(key != lag(key, default="0")) %>% 
  select(-key)
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, however in my actual case I have a lot more columns than just a, b and c. Is there a way to do it without naming them all?

Comment: I think we need the non-standard evaluation in this case. However, I didn't come up with a way to create key using `mutate_`. What I end up with is: `x$key <- apply(x[names(x[-1])], 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse="|"))`.